# logcat warning message : "showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection" in Android

Tags: android, service, connection, warnings

**Application Cycle :**
I have a `mainActivity`, which starts a service, bind with it, and `finish()` after X seconds, the bind should be broken but the service should keep running.
The service with a specific trigger will start the MainActivity again (startService will not be called , i check if the service already exists).

So on the first time mainActivity finishes, the warning doesn't appear, while on the second time and on it does.
I tried removing all relevant 'binding' calls so no bind will be made and the warning still appears, it leaves us with a single option :  is it because i start the service and not stopping it ? if so , how should I do it without getting this message ?

I start the Service using the following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockerService.class);
intent.addCategory("LockerServiceTag");
startService(intent);
```

The stop is from another activity and not relevant since its not the problem for sure.

I **DONT** want to stop service when exiting.

Any insights why this warning message happens ?